# Cross compilation of libical

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, uclibc, libical

I'm trying to port libical to a arm based platform but there's an error while compiling.
Here are the results of my build steps:

`$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/libical --build=i686-gnu-linux --host=arm-merlin-linux-uclibc`

```
checking build system type... i686-gnu-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc
checking target system type... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-strip... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc... gcc3
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++... gcc3
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... none needed
checking whether yytext is a pointer... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc... /opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/i686-linux/bin/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-nm -B
checking the name lister (/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/i686-linux/bin/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-gnu-linux-gnu file names to arm-merlin-linux-uclibc format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-gnu-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-objdump... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-ar... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-strip... (cached) arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-strip
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-ranlib... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-ranlib
checking command to parse /opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/i686-linux/bin/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-nm -B output from arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-mt... no
checking for mt... mt
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc linker (/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ -E
checking for ld used by arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++... /opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ linker (/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++ linker (/opt/mobilygen/tools/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-SDK7r4552/i686-linux/arm-merlin-linux-uclibc/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether the system provides zonefiles or we should bring our own? ... no
checking for Berkeley DB4 support... no
checking whether to support development... no
checking for ar... (cached) arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-ar
checking for perl5... no
checking for perl... perl
checking whether to define _REENTRANT... no
checking if icalerrors_* calls should abort instead of internally signalling an error... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking assert.h usability... yes
checking assert.h presence... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking wctype.h usability... yes
checking wctype.h presence... yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking endian.h usability... yes
checking endian.h presence... yes
checking for endian.h... yes
checking sys/endian.h usability... no
checking sys/endian.h presence... no
checking for sys/endian.h... no
checking byteswap.h usability... yes
checking byteswap.h presence... yes
checking for byteswap.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for isspace... yes
checking for iswspace... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating design-data/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating scripts/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libical/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libical/icalversion.h
config.status: creating src/libical/icalerror.h
config.status: creating src/libicalss/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libicalvcal/Makefile
config.status: creating src/test/Makefile
config.status: creating test-data/Makefile
config.status: creating libical.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

Looks fine for me so far.
Now building.

`$ make`

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0'
Making all in design-data
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/design-data'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/design-data'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/doc'
Making all in scripts
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/scripts'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/scripts'
Making all in test-data
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/test-data'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/test-data'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/src'
Making all in libical
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/src/libical'
perl -I ../../scripts ../../scripts/mkderivedparameters.pl -i ./icalderivedparameter.h.in -h ../../design-data/parameters.csv > icalderivedparameter.h 
perl  -I../../scripts ../../scripts/mkderivedproperties.pl \
        -i ./icalderivedproperty.h.in -h ../../design-data/properties.csv\
        ../../design-data/value-types.csv > icalderivedproperty.h 
perl -I../../scripts  ../../scripts/mkderivedvalues.pl \
             -i ./icalderivedvalue.h.in -h ../../design-data/value-types.csv > icalderivedvalue.h
perl -I ../../scripts ../../scripts/mkderivedparameters.pl -i ./icalderivedparameter.c.in -c ../../design-data/parameters.csv > icalderivedparameter.c
perl  -I../../scripts ../../scripts/mkderivedproperties.pl \
        -i ./icalderivedproperty.c.in -c ../../design-data/properties.csv \
        ../../design-data/value-types.csv > icalderivedproperty.c
perl  -I../../scripts ../../scripts/mkderivedvalues.pl \
        -i ./icalderivedvalue.c.in -c ../../design-data/value-types.csv > icalderivedvalue.c
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/src/libical'
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../src -I../../src -I../../src/libical -I../../src/libical -I. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/opt/libical/share/libical"\"   -g -O2 -MT icalderivedparameter.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/icalderivedparameter.Tpo -c -o icalderivedparameter.lo icalderivedparameter.c
mv -f .deps/icalderivedparameter.Tpo .deps/icalderivedparameter.Plo
mv: cannot stat `.deps/icalderivedparameter.Tpo': No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [icalderivedparameter.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/src/libical'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/src/libical'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libical-1.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The build environment is Debian 6 squeeze:

`uname -a`

`Linux 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux`

Compiler version is 4.2.1

Is there an error with the sources/build script?
A dependency problem?
How to fix this? It would be also ok if there's an alternative to libical as long it is written in c or c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. It seems that **libical does not support the ./configure method anymore**. You should use cmake(an up2date version, 2.8.2 didn't worked for me) instead.

For me, the build process now looks like this:

```
$ export CC=arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc
$ export CXX=arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-g++
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/cross/libical ..
...
$ make
...
$ make install
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I met your issue, and solve it by below steps:

1. make sure you have install libtool on your PC.
2. export YOUR CC/CXX/CFLAGE...LDFLAG
3. run ./bootstrap under the source code folder
4. run ./configure --build=i386-linux --host=arm-linux
5. make && make install

Hope it could help.